# Change active class when a menu item is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change the active class when I click one of the `items in the menu`, but how do I change the color on selected tab to another `active` tab and then remove the old one?

```css
.wdc-table-menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #484A51;
    border-top-right-radius: 0.938rem;
    border-top-left-radius: 0.938rem;
}

.wdc-table-menu li {
    float: left;
}

.wdc-table-menu li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-top-right-radius: 0.938rem;
    border-top-left-radius: 0.938rem;
}

.wdc-table-menu li a:hover {
    background-color: #3A3B41;
}

.wdc-table-menu .active {
    background-color: #3A3B41;
}

.wdc-table-title {
    text-align: center;
}

.wdc-table-title p {
    color: #D3D3D9;
    font-size: 2rem !important;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
    <div class="wdc-table-menu">
        <ul id="menu_wdc">
            <li><a class="wdc_btn active" href="#">WDC</a></li>
            <li><a class="wdc-btn" href="#">History</a></li>
            <li><a class="wdc-btn" href="#">Components</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change an element's class with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/how-can-i-change-an-elements-class-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would wanna use JavaScript to achieve this. Like so:

```js
const links =document.querySelectorAll(".wdc-btn ");
links.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
     e.preventDefault();
     document.querySelector(".wdc-btn.active").classList.remove("active");
     btn.classList.add("active")
  }));
```

```css
.wdc-table-menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #484A51;
    border-top-right-radius: 0.938rem;
    border-top-left-radius: 0.938rem;
}

.wdc-table-menu li {
    float: left;
}

.wdc-table-menu li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-top-right-radius: 0.938rem;
    border-top-left-radius: 0.938rem;
}

.wdc-table-menu li a:hover {
    background-color: #3A3B41;
}

.wdc-table-menu .active {
    background-color: #3A3B41;
}

.wdc-table-title {
    text-align: center;
}

.wdc-table-title p {
    color: #D3D3D9;
    font-size: 2rem !important;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="wdc-table-menu">
        <ul id="menu_wdc">
            <li><a class="wdc-btn active" href="#">WDC</a></li>
            <li><a class="wdc-btn" href="#">History</a></li>
            <li><a class="wdc-btn" href="#">Components</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pseudo-class `:focus`. Also an event `onclick` for remove `.active`:

```js
function myfunction(){
  document.getElementById("active").classList.remove("active");
}
```

```css
.wdc-table-menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #484A51;
    border-top-right-radius: 0.938rem;
    border-top-left-radius: 0.938rem;
}

.wdc-table-menu li {
    float: left;
}

.wdc-table-menu li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-top-right-radius: 0.938rem;
    border-top-left-radius: 0.938rem;
}

.wdc-table-menu li a:hover {
    background-color: #3A3B41;
}
.wdc-table-menu li .active{
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
.wdc-table-menu li a:focus{ /*here*/
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
.wdc-table-title {
    text-align: center;
}
.wdc-table-title p {
    color: #D3D3D9;
    font-size: 2rem !important;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="wdc-table-menu">
        <ul id="menu_wdc" onclick="myfunction()">
            <li><a id="active" class="wdc_btn active" href="#">WDC</a></li>
            <li><a class="wdc-btn" href="#">History</a></li>
            <li><a class="wdc-btn" href="#">Components</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```